# Javascript string variable to link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension and I want to convert my javascript string variable into a clickable link. This is what my code does right now,

```
var regex = /[\w]+[\/]+[\w]+#(?:\d*\.)?\d+/g;
```

This finds a format on a page e.g. stack/overflow#12453. I convert the regex into a string with this function

```
function objectToString(object) {

    var stringify = "";

    for (var property in object) {
        stringify += object[property] + '<br>';

}
    return stringify;
}
```

What i want to do is to make that string into a clickable link. So if there are 5 links on a page, each of the strings returned would be a clickable link to a href. Is this possible? I would gladly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 var obj = new Object();
    obj.link1 = "www.google.com";
    obj.link2 = "www.msn.com";

    $().ready(function () {       
        $.each(objectToString(obj).split(','), function (i) {
            $("ul").append("<li><a href=" + objectToString(obj).split(',')[i] + ">" + objectToString(obj).split(',')[i] + "</a></li>");
        });

    });

    function objectToString(object) {

        var stringify = "";

        for (var property in object) {
            stringify += object[property] + ",";
        }

        stringify = stringify.slice(0, stringify.length - 1);

        return stringify;
    }
```

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/u4hghL9c/